# Change devices in optical bay on the fly?

Tags: hotswapping, drive-bay

I'm wondering if there is any harm (e.g risk of data loss) in changing the device in my optical bay (e.g. from optical drive to HDD), while my operating system (BSD, Linux  or Windows) is running? I would of course unmount the HDD or SSD in the optical bay, before removing it.

I am asking generally for all kind of systems, but I am using a Lenovo T430. My OS is in the first drive, not the one in the bay.

Comment: That depends on your laptop’s(?) make and model.

Comment: Ask the fly its opinion first.

Comment: Added make and model

Comment: Why not leave the optical in and use an external usb enclosure for the hard drive?

Comment: I don't need the optical bay, and I am using an 128gb ssd for my operating system, and a 500gb sshd for all my personal data and configs. The folders are symlinked (softlink) on my Unix machine:  "ln -s /dev/sdb1/Documents ~/Documents" and so on. In the rare scenario I need a cd, I create a disk image file. My backups are on my USB drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction. Not all consumer pcs are capable of hot swapping drives.

Regardless, I recommend turning off your computer anytime you're adding or taking components out. You don't want to short circuit anything while you're working on your pc. Yes hardware is alot more resistant to static electricity and much more, but why take the chance. Typically when hard drives are hot swapped, they're in enclosures or servers that make it really easy to swap out.

On windows computers, you'll have to go to Disk Management and make sure to initialize hdd otherwise it will not show up in windows explorer or have a drive letter assigned to it.

Comment: Hot swap is only supported if the sata driver supports it, most consumer pc's do not support hot swap.

Comment: Gotcha @ Moab 
So just turn off your personal computer and call it a day. :)

Comment: I think systems should be designed with short-circuit prevention in mind, and I am willing to take the Chance (after I made a backup). I like your answer but as @ndocds mentioned, shouldn't all SATA devices be hot swappable?

Answer (score 0):

SATA is advertised as "Hot Swappable" and is done in an enterprise environment all the time. Older operating systems won't recognize the drive some times. You cannot swap your primary drive that your OS is running on.

Comment: I didn't know of the feature "hot swappable" and that this is used all the time in production. Thank you!

Comment: You can purchase items such as: Just ensure you dismount the drive. I use a SATA external enclosure to hot swap drives at home all the time. At work my server has 4 hot swappable bays
https://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-External-Duplicator-Function-EC-HD2B/dp/B0759567JT/ref=sr_1_7?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1550788627&sr=1-7&keywords=SATA+Hard+Drive+Docking+Station

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I needed this, but I felt that something was missing :`-)